# dot2tex concentrate edges, bug fix or workaround

Tags: tikz-pgf, dot2tex

It is a [known bug](http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/documentation/#issues-and-limitations) that dot2tex produces weird output when combining `concentrate=true` and *tikz* code output. It creates multiple squiggly edges instead of one nice curved edges. However, we get semi-nice output when generating PGF code but still isn't quite right.

Has someone found a fix to this bug? Or possibly a workaround to get the final result I'm getting at? I want two incoming edges to flow together nicely and have one label on the arrow head side.

[image: Example of PGF output]
[image: Example of Tikz output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{dot2texi}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{var} = [draw,shape=rectangle,minimum size=2em,
                        inner sep=2pt,fill=white!20]


\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{dot2tex}[dot,pgf,options=-tmath]
digraph G {
    [concentrate=true, rankdir=LR]
    node [style="var"]
    x [label="x"]
    y [label="y"]
    i_1 [texlbl="i1 = 0"]
    i_2 [texlbl="i2 = 1"]
    o_1 [texlbl="o2 = 0"]
    o_2 [texlbl="o2 = 1"]
    x -> i_1;
    x -> i_2;
    i_1 -> o_1 [texlbl="fib", label="fib", rankdir="LR"];
    i_2 -> o_2 [texlbl="fib", label="fib", rankdir="LR"];
    o_1 -> y [rankdir="LR"]
    o_2 -> y [rankdir="LR"]
    }
\end{dot2tex}
\caption{PGF output}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{dot2tex}[dot,tikz,options=-tmath]
digraph G {
    [concentrate=true, rankdir=LR]
    node [style="var"]
    x [label="x"]
    y [label="y"]
    i_1 [texlbl="i1 = 0"]
    i_2 [texlbl="i2 = 1"]
    o_1 [texlbl="o2 = 0"]
    o_2 [texlbl="o2 = 1"]
    x -> i_1;
    x -> i_2;
    i_1 -> o_1 [texlbl="fib", label="fib", rankdir="LR"];
    i_2 -> o_2 [texlbl="fib", label="fib", rankdir="LR"];
    o_1 -> y [rankdir="LR"]
    o_2 -> y [rankdir="LR"]
    }
\end{dot2tex}
\caption{TIKZ output}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution is technically classified as a *workaround* I suppose. I drew it with only `tikz`.

**The code:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  -latex,
  ell/.style={draw,ellipse,minimum height=3em,minimum width=5em}
]
  \node[ell] at (0,0)     (x)      {$x$};
  \node[ell,right=of x]   (i1)  {i$1=0$};
  \node[ell,below=of i1]  (i2)  {i$2=1$};
  \node[ell,right=of i1]  (o2t) {o$2=0$};
  \node[ell,below=of o2t] (o2b) {o$2=1$};
  \node[ell,right=of o2t] (y)      {$y$};
  \draw (x)   -- (i1)  coordinate[pos=0.25] (branch);
  \draw (o2t) -- (y)   coordinate[pos=0.75]  (merge);
  \draw (i1)  -- (o2t) node[midway,above]      {fib};
  \draw (i2)  -- (o2b) node[midway,above]      {fib};
  \draw    (branch) to[out=0]     (i2);
  \draw[-] (o2b)    to[in=180] (merge);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**The output:**
[image]

The `out` and `in` angles as well as the branch and merge `pos`itions can easily be changed if required.